# Python Pandas - Condicional string parcial dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou com uma seguinte situação:
Possuo um dataframe:

```
data = {"Id": ["01", "02", "03", "04",'05'],"Fruta": ['Maçã','Abacaxi','Banana','Laranja','Morango']}
base_dados = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(base_dados)

    Id  Fruta
0   01  Maçã
1   02  Abacaxi
2   03  Banana
3   04  Laranja
4   05  Morango
```

Preciso procurar inserir uma condicional de uma string parcial.. Tipo

```
if 'Abac' in base_dados['Fruta']: #encontrou o abacaxi
    print('Encontrou o Abacaxi em uma coluna de dataframe pela parcial de uma string')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa percorrer os itens da coluna e após isso verificar se existe a `string` no texto, assim:

```
for i in base_dados['Fruta']:
  if 'Abac' in i:
    print('Encontrou o Abacaxi em uma coluna de dataframe pela parcial de uma string')
```

Comment: Que simples! Funcionou, obrigado.